# How to check if gorm save() updated any values in mysql

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to work out what the best way to check if the values that I'm saving have overwritten any that are in the database.

Obviously, I can get a record, compare the data and then save if it's different, but I wondered if there was a way to know inherently when a Save is done?

I can use update - and it will give back a row affected value > 1 but the problem with that is that update can't update a value in the db to a Go default type value (0 for example) therefore that won't work for this case.

For example:

```
db.Table("object").Where("id = ?", obj).Save(obj)
log.Println(res.RowsAffected) // always equals 1
```

compared to

```
res := db.Table("object").Where("id = ?", obj).Update(obj)
log.Println(res.RowsAffected) // equals 1 if updated
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to re-read the value you've updated?  Or you just want to know _if_ something was updated?

Comment: Literally if any of the values in the data that's going into the Update/Save method have updated any values in the database. 

My use case is taking data from an API and storing it for use in a database - so by checking if the data has been updated I can decide whether to fire off events.